Problems with PyQt5
I try to change my Sankey Diagram Generator GUI from Tkinter to PyQt5. I try to go by documentation and bit of experimentation but can't find why some things are happening.
The code is divided into the frames. The left frame gets the node labels and also the flow values and the right frame will be for specific node information (like in which level it is).
I didn't wanted it to make too complicated yet so it does not demand any new rows for the nodes, just 2 rows for the inputs currently.
When a node is entered on the left frame it is displayed on the right frame for the node specific options. However, when a node textbox on the left frame is updated (Either by removing the value or adding a multi character value) the margins suddenly increases. I couldn't find why this happens.
Also I couldn't make the titles aligned and on the very top. The left and right frame titles doesn't want to align and there is much free space in the window above everything else. Is that normal for PyQT5? Why can't I put the titles on the very top.
This is the current code:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSplitter, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey

class SankeyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("SankeyFlow Diagram Creator")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 800)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)

        #Left Frame: Node and Flow Inputs
        left_frame = QWidget()
        left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        left_layout.setSpacing(2)  
        left_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  


        header_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        header_layout.setSpacing(5)
        header_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Node 1"))
        header_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Node 2"))
        header_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Flow"))
        left_layout.addLayout(header_layout)

        self.node_inputs = []
        self.flow_inputs = []

        for i in range(2):  # Initial two rows for inputs
            row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            row_layout.setSpacing(5)  

            node1_input = QLineEdit()
            node2_input = QLineEdit()
            flow_input = QLineEdit()

            row_layout.addWidget(node1_input)
            row_layout.addWidget(node2_input)
            row_layout.addWidget(flow_input)

            left_layout.addLayout(row_layout)
            self.node_inputs.append((node1_input, node2_input))
            self.flow_inputs.append(flow_input)

        generate_button = QPushButton("Generate Sankey Diagram")
        generate_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_sankey)
        left_layout.addWidget(generate_button)

        # Connect text change events for each node input
        for node1, node2 in self.node_inputs:
            node1.textChanged.connect(self.update_right_frame)
            node2.textChanged.connect(self.update_right_frame)

        left_frame.setLayout(left_layout)

        right_frame = QWidget()
        right_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        right_layout.setSpacing(5)  
        right_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)


        node_values_header = QHBoxLayout()
        node_values_header.setSpacing(5)
        node_values_header.addWidget(QLabel("Nodes"))
        node_values_header.addWidget(QLabel("Values"))
        right_layout.addLayout(node_values_header)

        self.node_value_inputs_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.node_value_inputs_layout.setSpacing(5)
        right_layout.addLayout(self.node_value_inputs_layout)

        right_frame.setLayout(right_layout)

        self.node_values = {}  

        splitter.addWidget(left_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(right_frame)
        splitter.setSizes([600, 600])  
        splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 1)

        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
        main_layout.setSpacing(0)  
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) 
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

    def update_right_frame(self):
        """Update the right frame with nodes as they are typed in the left frame."""
        current_nodes = set()
        for node1, node2 in self.node_inputs:
            node1_label = node1.text().strip()
            node2_label = node2.text().strip()

            if node1_label:
                current_nodes.add(node1_label)
            if node2_label:
                current_nodes.add(node2_label)

        # Sort nodes alphabetically
        sorted_nodes = sorted(current_nodes)

        for node_label in sorted_nodes:
            if node_label not in self.node_values:
                node_row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
                node_row_layout.setSpacing(5) 
                label_widget = QLabel(f"{node_label}:")
                input_widget = QLineEdit()

                input_widget.setFixedWidth(150) 
                input_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

                node_row_layout.addWidget(label_widget)
                node_row_layout.addWidget(input_widget)
                self.node_value_inputs_layout.addLayout(node_row_layout)

                self.node_values[node_label] = (label_widget, input_widget)


        for node_label in list(self.node_values.keys()):
            if node_label not in current_nodes:
                label_widget, input_widget = self.node_values.pop(node_label)
                label_widget.deleteLater()  
                input_widget.deleteLater()  

        self.node_value_inputs_layout.setSpacing(5)  
        self.node_value_inputs_layout.update()

    def generate_sankey(self):
        flows = []
        nodes = []

        for i, (node1, node2) in enumerate(self.node_inputs):
            node1_label = node1.text().strip()
            node2_label = node2.text().strip()
            flow_value = self.flow_inputs[i].text().strip()

            try:
                flow_value = float(flow_value) if flow_value else 0
            except ValueError:
                flow_value = 0

            # Create the nodes and flow entries
            if node1_label and node2_label:
                nodes.append([(f'{node1_label}:', abs(flow_value))])
                nodes.append([(f'{node2_label}:', abs(flow_value))])
                flows.append((f'{node1_label}:', f'{node2_label}:', flow_value))

        # Display the Sankey diagram
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=144)
        s = Sankey(flows=flows, nodes=nodes, node_opts=dict(label_format='{label} {value:.2f}%'))
        s.draw()
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = SankeyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


I tried setting spacing, limiting the window for the frames. Removed the margins for the titles so they would go to the top. But neither of these methods solved the problems.

Please edit the question and add a picture (cropped screenshot) of 1. the desired look from TkInter 2. the current look in PyQt. Then please also add some default values for the text boxes so that we can easily add a new node and reproduce the issue. For me, your code crashes because it's not clear what fields should be filled out and with what.

my Sankey Diagram Generator GUI Please add a link to the GitHub page with the project, if it's open source.

For future reference, choose more clear and verbose titles for your posts, as "Problems with PyQt5" is a terrible choice, since it forces everybody to open the post and fully read it. A lot of people would completely ignore such a post to begin with, including those who would've been able to help you. The title should always summarize the problem, and that's important for other people too, as they may have a similar issue. Imagine searching for a solution about your problem and just finding hundreds of posts titled "Problems with PyQt5", with most of them unrelated to your issue.


I couldn't make the titles aligned and on the very top.

Independent horizontal layouts will not align properly and are just complicating matters. Use QGridLayout directly. I've refactored the code a bit. Hopefully it does what you want.
In the code below, there's a headers option that you can change to choose where the headers go - top vs. near the contents.

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
from enum import Enum


class Headers(Enum):
    TOP = "Top"
    WITH_CONTENTS = "WithContents"


class SankeyWindow(QWidget):
    node_inputs: list[tuple[QLineEdit, QLineEdit]] = []
    flow_inputs: list[QLineEdit] = []
    node_values: dict = {}
    right_layout: QGridLayout

    def make_left_frame(self, headers: Headers):
        frame = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(frame)

        if headers == Headers.TOP:
            header_row, stretch_row = (0, 1)
        elif headers == Headers.WITH_CONTENTS:
            header_row, stretch_row = (1, 0)

        layout.setRowStretch(stretch_row, 10)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Node 1"), header_row, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Node 2"), header_row, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Flow"), header_row, 2)

        for i in range(2):  # Initial two rows for inputs
            node1_input = QLineEdit()
            node2_input = QLineEdit()
            flow_input = QLineEdit()

            layout.addWidget(node1_input, 2+i, 0)
            layout.addWidget(node2_input, 2+i, 1)
            layout.addWidget(flow_input, 2+i, 2)

            self.node_inputs.append((node1_input, node2_input))
            self.flow_inputs.append(flow_input)

        generate_button = QPushButton("Generate Sankey Diagram")
        generate_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_sankey)
        layout.addWidget(generate_button, layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, 3)
        return frame

    def make_right_frame(self, headers: Headers):
        frame = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(frame)
        self.right_layout = layout

        if headers == Headers.TOP:
            header_row, stretch_row = (0, 1)
        elif headers == Headers.WITH_CONTENTS:
            header_row, stretch_row = (1, 0)

        layout.setRowStretch(stretch_row, 10)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Nodes"), header_row, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Values"), header_row, 1)
        return frame

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("SankeyFlow Diagram Creator")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 800)

        left_frame = self.make_left_frame(Headers.TOP)
        right_frame = self.make_right_frame(Headers.WITH_CONTENTS)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.addWidget(left_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(right_frame)
        splitter.setSizes([600, 600])
        QVBoxLayout(self).addWidget(splitter)

        # Connect text change events for each node input
        for node1, node2 in self.node_inputs:
            node1.textChanged.connect(self.update_right_frame)
            node2.textChanged.connect(self.update_right_frame)

    def update_right_frame(self):
        """Update the right frame with nodes as they are typed in the left frame."""
        current_nodes = set()
        for node1, node2 in self.node_inputs:
            node1_label = node1.text().strip()
            node2_label = node2.text().strip()

            if node1_label:
                current_nodes.add(node1_label)
            if node2_label:
                current_nodes.add(node2_label)

        # Sort nodes alphabetically
        sorted_nodes = sorted(current_nodes)

        for node_label in sorted_nodes:
            if node_label not in self.node_values:
                r = self.right_layout.rowCount()

                label_widget = QLabel(f"{node_label}:")
                input_widget = QLineEdit()

                self.right_layout.addWidget(label_widget, r, 0)
                self.right_layout.addWidget(input_widget, r, 1)

                self.node_values[node_label] = (label_widget, input_widget)

        for node_label in list(self.node_values.keys()):
            if node_label not in current_nodes:
                label_widget, input_widget = self.node_values.pop(node_label)
                label_widget.deleteLater()
                input_widget.deleteLater()

    def generate_sankey(self):
        flows: list[tuple[str, str, float]] = []
        nodes: list[list[tuple[str, float]]] = []

        for i, (node1, node2) in enumerate(self.node_inputs):
            node1_label = node1.text().strip()
            node2_label = node2.text().strip()
            flow_value_str = self.flow_inputs[i].text()

            try:
                flow_value = float(flow_value_str)
            except ValueError:
                flow_value = 0.0

            # Create the nodes and flow entries
            if node1_label and node2_label:
                nodes.append([(f'{node1_label}:', abs(flow_value))])
                nodes.append([(f'{node2_label}:', abs(flow_value))])
                flows.append((f'{node1_label}:', f'{node2_label}:', flow_value))

        # Display the Sankey diagram
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=144)
        s = Sankey(flows=flows, nodes=nodes, node_opts={'label_format': '{label} {value:.2f}%'})
        s.draw()
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SankeyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()



Note:

To get an "empty" area in a layout, add a stretch to the layout. In a grid layout, that means set a stretch on the row or column, and don't add any widgets to that row/column:
layout = QGridLayout(myWidget)
layout.addWidget(QLabel("Header"), 0, 0)
layout.setRowStretch(1, 10)
layout.addWidget(QLabel("Footer"), 2, 0)


An application's main window should be a QWidget or QDialog unless there is a specific reason you need QMainWindow's features - typically those would be dockable sub-windows.

A layout can be set on a widget directly when constructing the layout. You don't need to wait to set the layout until the layout is "finished".
# concise
widget = QWidget()
layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)

# verbose
widget = QWidget()
layout = QHBoxLayout()
widget.setLayout(layout)


It helps to have type annotations.

Member variables can be declared and initialized in the class scope. When a type annotation is present, they are not class variables. They are just members, except their declarations are not buried in the __init__ method:
# more visible
class Foo:
    class_field: typing.ClassVar[int] = 42   # class field
    field: int = 0                           # instance field

# less visible
class Foo:
    class_field = 42

    def __init__(self):
        self.field = 0



